# taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection never called in Alamofire 5

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Updating Alamofire to 5.0.4. As the title says `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection` is never called.

In Alamofire 4.x we could do something like:

```
  let sessionDelegate =  request.session.delegate as! Alamofire.SessionDelegate

  sessionDelegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
    if let url = task.currentRequest?.url {
        // look at redirected url & act accordingly
      }
    }
  }
```

A request's session/delegate has been overhauled in Alamofire 5 and is no longer directly accessible from the request. More specifically, `taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection` is a closure callback on `ClosureEventMonitor`. As a sanity check, I tested using some of the other closure callbacks.. and they worked.

```
// ClosureEventMonitor

  let monitor = ClosureEventMonitor()
  monitor.requestDidCreateTask = { request, task in
     // Event fires
  }

  let monitor2 = ClosureEventMonitor()
  monitor2.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { sess, task, resp, req in
   // Event Never fires
  }

  monitor2.requestDidFinish = { request in
    // Event Fires
  }

  // Set up Session
  var session: Session? = Session(startRequestsImmediately: false, eventMonitors: [monitor, monitor2])

  let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
  let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

  let trequest = session?.request(urlRequest)
```

For reference this code is being fired from my `AppDelegate` `func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity` for handling deep/universal links.

I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three things here:

First, `session?.request(urlRequest)` will never actually make a request, since you never call `resume()` (or attach a response handler).

Second, using a one off `Session` like that is not recommended. As soon as the `Session` goes out of scope all requests will be cancelled.

Third, `EventMonitor`s cannot interact with the request pipeline, they're only observational. Instead, use Alamofire 5's new `RedirectHandler` protocol or `Redirector` type to handle redirects. There is more in [our documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#redirecthandler). A simple implementation that customizes the action performed would be:

```swift
let redirector = Redirector(behavior: .modify { task, request, response in
    // Customize behavior.
})
session?.request(urlRequest).redirect(using: redirector)
```